# non constant regular function derivative is zero

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, kahler-differentials

Let $R$ be a Noetherian regular  $k$-algebra (where $k$ any field of char = 0) of dimension greater than 0. Is it true that $H^{0}_{dR}(R \lvert k) = k$?.

More generally we could ask, Is it true that $H^{0}_{dR}(R \lvert k)$ is finite $k$-algebra?

In other words I am asking suppose a regular function $P \in R$ such that its derivative is zero i.e. $d(P) = 0$ in $\Omega^{1}_{R}$, then does $P$ necessarily belongs to $k$? where, $d : R \rightarrow \Omega^{1}_{R}$ is the Kahler derivation.

I know this holds for polynomial algebra and I thought it should be consistent with the fact in manifold that a smooth function which derivative is zero must be constant.

Comment: Probably you want to assume $Spec(R)$ is connected?

Comment: Sure we can assume that as this is also needed in manifold case as well.

Comment: Take $k=\mathbb{Q}$ and $R$ be any finite extension .

Comment: Ok well you are right. But in some sense these are kind of trivial counter example which I don't want. May be I should be precise about my question and should say dimension of R is greater than 0.

Comment: OK, building on Mohan's comment, take $R=\mathbb{Q}(i)[x]$. A bit more precision perhaps?

Comment: I think the correct statement should be that $H^0_{\rm dR}(R/k)$ is a finite $k$-algebra (and hence a product of finite field extensions).

Comment: Yes I agree with @Achinger. May be I should edit the question.

Comment: Answer to your edit: no. Take $k=\mathbb{Q}$, $R=\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[x]$.

Comment: It seems like only possible counter example to the above claim are of the same flavour i. e. Take an algebaric extension of rational so that it's module of differential is zero and attach finite many variable. Is it true these are the only possible way the above claim could fail.